# Generate Tomcat web.xml configuration from UML digram

Tags: uml, web.xml, eclipse-emf, xmi

I would like to find the best way to parse an UML Diagram that detail the security tomcat configuration for a web application, then generate the concerned file (web.xml).

For the beginning, I have a Metamodel and his instance created with Magic Draw, I have to export them and use them in a kind of java application (plugin? API?) then parse and validate them against some constraint (OCL?) finally I have to generate the Web.xml file.

So, I made some research and I found that I can use EMF to catch my models, but its not so clear and handily to create a peace of java code that can handle my model remotely from an URI then validate em.

Do you have any suggestions/advises to made this please? Do I must use EMF? or there is another framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.xml from UML?  Sorry, I don't think it's a useful idea.  It doesn't take long to hand edit such a thing.  The effort it would take to automate such a thing wouldn't be worth it.  I'd open up a text editor, create the web.xml, and spend the time you save doing more useful things.

But, if you must, I'd find a way to export your object model into an XML document.  I'd parse that into a DOM tree, walk the tree, and emit the elements I needed into a web.xml.

I know that Magic Draw has the capability to export UML as XML.  See if that helps you.

But there's no way to do it directly from the Magic Draw tool that I know of.  You'll have to write this Java post-process and run it on the command line using the exported model XML as input.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I have a research project, and this part have to work in that way because we have many model, many web application and we want to have a generic security constraint. So the security team have just to put a security diagram then run a kind of plugins/API that will automatically generate the security constraint part on the web.xml

Comment: I'd write a simple class that could take in a web.xml file, parse it into a DOM tree, and add the generic security constraint.  It's generating it from UML that I object to.

Comment: Actually, I must use the object diagram as a starting point... its so weird but this is the only way that I must follow... I have to find out how to come from an object diagram to a Web.xml file